# Finding extremal values on a set

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let $f(x,y)=(x-1)^2+y^2+xy$. Find the maximal and minimal values of $f$ on the set $M=\{(x,y):|x|+|y|\leq4\}$.

**Attempt:** By taking partial derivatives and solving the homogenous algebraic system we obtain $f(\frac43,-\frac23)=-\frac13$ which we can check is a local minimum and the only local extremum on the plane.

Furthermore, $f(-2,-2)=16$. How can we prove that indeed $16$ is the maximum? I tried assuming to the contrary but did not get to $|x|+|y|>4$.

How can we see that $f$ does not get smaller than $\frac13$ on the contour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on daw's answer, you can show the function is convex by looking at the Hessian. The set $M$ is also convex since it is an intersection of 4 halfspaces.

Since $(4/3, -2/3)$ solves the first order conditions, it must be a local minimum. The optimization problem is convex (convex function over convex set), so the point is also a global minimum.

$(-2, -2)$ is not a maximum btw. Also $f(-2,-2) = -3^2 + -2^2 + (-2 \ \times -2) = 17$. The argument to find the max is not as straightforward. I think you can argue that since the only solution to the first order conditions is a local min, the global max must lie on the boundary. You can then examine the boundary points and argue that the max is achieved at $(-4,0)$. I haven't verified this though.

Comment: Ah, but $(-5,0)$ is outside the rectangle.

Comment: Sorry I meant $(-4,0)$. Edited my answer. Note, $f(-4,0) = 25$.

Answer (score 0):

The point $x^*=(4/3,-2/3)$ is an interior point of $M$. The function $f$ is convex. This should help to prove that $f$ attains at $x^*$ its global minimum.